# How to wrap net.Conn.Read() in Golang

Tags: go, ssl

I want to wrap `Read` function net.Conn.Read(). The purpose of this to read the SSL handshake messages. https://pkg.go.dev/net#TCPConn.Read

```
nc, err := net.Dial("tcp", "google.com:443")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
tls.Client(nc, &tls.Config{})
```

Are there any ways to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to intercept Read on a net.Conn:

```
 type wrap {
     // Conn is the wrapped net.Conn.
     // Because it's an embedded field, the 
     // net.Conn methods are automatically promoted
     // to wrap.
     net.Conn 
 }

 // Read calls through to the wrapped read and
 // prints the bytes that flow through. Replace
 // the print statement with whatever is appropriate
 // for your application.
 func (w wrap) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
     n, err := w.Conn.Read()
     fmt.Printf("%x\n", p[:n]) // example
     return n, err
 }
```

Wrap like this:

```
 tnc, err :=tls.Client(wrap{nc}, &tls.Config{})
```

Comment: Thank you!. I found it after a few attempts.

Answer (score -2):

The previous answer gets the job done indeed.

However I would recommend Liz Rice's talk: [GopherCon 2018: Liz Rice - The Go Programmer's Guide to Secure Connections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxKLYDLzuHA)

Going through her code in [Github](https://github.com/lizrice/secure-connections), you might find a more elegant way to achieve what you want.

Start with the [client code](https://github.com/lizrice/secure-connections/blob/master/client/main.go) on line 26.

Comment: Downvoted because this answer contains only links to other resources, without actually answering the question. Please  provide the *"more elegant way"* you mention directly in your question, instead of expecting others to find it by studying the repository or talk you linked.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I can take a downvote, no worries. You can watch the video and then you can tell me how you would do it differently. Everything in there is relevant and if I give here the exact solution I would deprive the user from a great opportunity to learn. So yes, study the repository. it's good for you

Comment: *"I can take a downvote, no worries"* - I'm not worried about you taking the downvote, but I'm worried about the usefulness of answers given here. It might well be that the 40 min video is worth watching and that the code is worth studying. But only pointing to external resources without giving at least a helpful technical summary is basically just another form of [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM).